# Symfony extends entity

Tags: symfony, orm

its posible to extend entity group by other entity gtoup also changin OneToOne/OneToMany relations.

For example i tried to exted UserTemp by User but on schema validation i receive error of mapping invalid.

class User

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="d1_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var UserAddress
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserAdress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $address;
}
```

class UserTemp

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="d1_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserTempRepository")
 */
class UserTemp extends User
{
    /**
     * @var UserTempAddress
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserTempAdress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $address;
}
```

Comment: Read about *class table inheritance* and *single table inheritance*: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping and then how to override the association: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override

Answer (score 0):

You try

```
/**
 * @EntityExtension("User") //path Class User
 */
trait UserTempTrait
{
    /**
     * @var UserTempAddress
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserTempAdress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $address;
}
```